# Keeping integrity between two separate data stores during backups (MySQL and MongoDB)

Tags: mysql, mongodb, backup

I have an application I designed where relational data sits and fits naturally into MySQL. I have other data that has a constantly evolving schema and doesn't have relational data, so I figured the natural way to store this data would be in MongoDB as a document. My issue here is one of my documents references a MySQL primary ID. So far this has worked without any issues. My concern is that when production traffic comes in and we start working with backups, that there might be inconsistency for when the document changes, it might not point to the correct ID in the MySQL database. The only way to guarantee it to a certain degree would be to shutdown the application and take backups, which doesn't make much sense.

There has to be other people that deploy a similar strategy. What is the best way to ensure data integrity between the two data stores, particularly during backups?

Comment: Not meaning to shoot this down as I'm not super experienced with Mongo, and I would love to hear from anyone that's tried this and had success, but my hunch is that you're going to struggle greatly if you're trying to hold tight relational integrity on MongoDB data like that. Its specifically designed to make the trade of sacrificing integrity for scale :/

Answer (score 4):

## MySQL Perspective

All your MySQL data would have to use InnoDB. Then you could make a snapshot of the MySQL Data as follows:

```
MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS="--single-transaction --routines --triggers"
mysqldump -u... -p... ${MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS} --all-databases > MySQLData.sql
```

This will create a clean point-in-time snapshot of all MySQL Data as a single transaction.

For instance, if you start this mysqldump at midnight, all data in the mysqldump output will be from midnight. Data can still be added to MySQL (provided all your data uses the InnoDB Storage Engine) and you can have MongoDB reference any new data added to MySQL after midnight, even if it is during the backup.

If you have any MyISAM tables, you need to convert them to InnoDB. Let's cut to the chase. Here is how you make a script to convert all your MyISAM tables to InnoDB:

```
MYISAM_TO_INNODB_CONVERSION_SCRIPT=/root/ConvertMyISAMToInnoDB.sql
echo "SET SQL_LOG_BIN = 0;" > ${MYISAM_TO_INNODB_CONVERSION_SCRIPT}
mysql -u... -p... -AN -e"SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ',table_schema,'.',table_name,' ENGINE=InnoDB;') InnoDBConversionSQL FROM information_schema.tables WHERE engine='MyISAM' AND table_schema NOT IN ('information_schema','mysql','performance_schema') ORDER BY (data_length+index_length)" >> ${MYISAM_TO_INNODB_CONVERSION_SCRIPT}
```

Just run this script when you are ready to convert all user-defined MyISAM tables. Any system-related MyISAM tables are ignored and should not be touched anyway.

## MongoDB Perspective

I cannot speak for MongoDB for I know very little. Yet, for the MongoDB side of things, if you setup a Replica Set for any MongoDB data, you could just use mongodump against a replica. Since mongodump is not point-in-time, you would have to disconnect the replica (to stop changes from coming over) and then perform the mongodump on the replica. Then reestablish the replica to its master. Find out from your developers or from 10gen if mongodump can be used against a disconnected replica set.

## Common Objectives

If point-in-time truly matters to you, please makes sure all OS clocks have the same synchronized time and timezone. If you have to perform such a synchronization, your must restart mysqld and mongod. Then, your crontab jobs for mysqldump and mongodump will go off at the same time. Personally, I would delay a mongodump about 30 seconds to assure the ids from mysql you want posted in MongoDB are accounted for.

If you have mysqld and mongod running on the same server, then you do not need any MongoDB replication. Just start a mysqldump at 00:00:00 (midnight) and the mongodump at 00:30:00 (30 sec after midnight).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is an easy way to do this. Mongo doesn't have complex transactions with rollback support so its very hard to maintain such integrity. One way to approach this would be to think of it as two ledgers, records all the updates on mysql ledger and then replay it on mongo ledger to maintain integrity. The other possible solution is to do this at the application level and stop the writes.

Answer (score 0):

There really is no way to do it without some kind of outside check or enforcement.

If you really need to ensure perfect integrity between the two, one way to do this is to use timestamps for both your mysql data (all records) and mongo records, then back up each one filtered by the timestamps using the tools for each to select only the the records existing right before the scheduled backup (see http://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysqldump-selectively-dump-data/ for how to use mysqldump with a WHERE clause and http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Import+Export+Tools#ImportExportTools-mongodump to dump a MongoDB collection with a query)

Depending on how you're actually using each of your data stores, you may be able to do something else... For example, if you are only writing to your MongoDB and never updating or deleting, then it would be reasonable to backup your MySQL database, then backup you MongoDB (which may now have some extra records in it because it is backed up afterwards) and then purge the MongoDB records that do not correspond to anything in MySQL.  As I said, it depends on how you're using them.

But the timestamp thing will work regardless - you just have the extra overhead of the timestamps.

Comment: You could alternative use auto-increment IDs provided of course that you have these in your schema. 
    mysqldump -uuser -p mydb --tables my_documents_table --where="id<=2000122" | gzip > my_documents_table_YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.sql.gz
    mysqldump -uuser -p mydb --ignore-table=mydb.my_documents_table | gzip > mydb_YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.sql.gz
You can then use the mongodump utility to select only records including your selected document ID range.